Controlling an animated shader with a proximity Geo nodes
I am trying to use Geo Nodes to control my animated shader on multiple objects. What I want is to use an object so that when it comes closer to objects, it starts to animate and eventually becomes completely red when it has passed by.
This is how I animated the shader, and how I want it the look when I control the distances with a proximity node.

And this is how i built ut:

Next I used Geometry proximity and attribute node to put in the FAC for the Less than node,
What I have done is that I have used the Proximity node and Attribute and put in the FAC for the Less than node so when I comes closer the more the objects would become red.
This is how I built it:

Unfortunately, the result is like this:

Here are the blender files:


Edit:
Tried @Lutzi solution with:
Position>Separate>X with Object Info of the cube > Separate>X

Result:

Is it possible to make the shader animation linger on and at the same time move onto the next one?
@Lutz solution:


What about just testing the x-positions ? As you stated your question, it'd solve it.

I get the same resualt when using x-position

I meaned without Geometry Proximity, just comparing Position>Separate>X with Object Info of the cube > Separate>X ?

Ultimately the problem here comes down to the fact each frame in Blender is rendered separately. So at the end of the animation the logic "doesn't know" it is not the start of the animation. You can be smart about it, and instead of calculating distance, you can check the object X, and "clamp it" (if x is higher than self x, then consider it to be 0, otherwise calculate the difference), or you can use some Blender feature that holds state, the most appropriate here would be a simulation zone.

I feel like this would be far easier if you used dynamic paint and vertex colors.

Thank you for taking the time to respond, it is appreciated! I am quite new to Geo Nodes / shader animation. If I want to go the smart way you are talking about to "clamp it," how would you go about it? @Markus von Broady

That actually works @Lutzi , but is it possible to make the shader animation linger on and at the sane time move onto the next one? I can make an edit how it looks now.

as for the edit: try multiplying the "x" by some value.

You could for example store on each vertex the frame it turned on, then turn it off if current time exceeds the value + a margin (with a simulation zone).

Simple dynamic setup with Geometry Nodes
I'm using an empty as a controller. I didn't see why you would want to use Geometry Proximity so I took the liberty to discard your cube controller.
Here is the most simple setup I can think of :

The idea is to store at which frame the face has been activated. By doing that, we can measure how long since activation. Here are the steps :

Initialize default value for activationFrame (should be negative and far greater than the duration of lingering activation, i.e. if we want faces to stay activated 50 frame, let's use -1000 to be safe).
Inside the Simulation Zone, test the distance and update the activationFrame if needed.
At the very end, we can simply choose the condition on which a face is activated or not.


You could add a lot of improvements here and there, for example you could store in each face for how long it should stay activated (to do before Simulation Zone). That way, you can add randomness.
Also, concerning the materials you should follow the answer of Chris instead of mine. Having 2 materials doesn't make sense and you can't have both at the same time, so it won't be smooth.

Thanks for your response. I'm trying to get your solution to work, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I've uploaded the file in the thread @Lutzi.

My screenshot is misleading : the last subtract node should have inputs switched, so that we get current - activationFrame. Also, I strongly recommend you to use the Spreadsheet window.

If I understand you correctly, the Named Attribute will be in the lower socket and Scene Time in the upper socket of the Subtract node? Thank you for your response!

Yes, if you want to keep the Less Than node as is.

Thanks so much for your help. I’m still having trouble getting it to work. Do you have any other tips? @Lutzi

@N03 Besides staying hydrated, no.

Alright, thank you!

As Lutzi said, you can use the simulation zone, so that your "old values" won't get deleted on each frame.
If you are using this node tree:

and this shader node tree:

you will get:


Thank you very much for your response, I truly appreciate it. I have attempted to follow your solution, but unfortunately, I am unable to get it to work. Could you please help me understand why? I've uploaded the file in the edit

Sorry, I forgot to mention your nick @Chris and now I cant edit the post!

[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/65mhEhtB.png -> you didn't put "dist" in the store named attribute node and you did put a value (dist) in the group output. Delete the value from the group output and enter "dist" into the store named attribute node.

Thanks that worked very well! if I want the animation, like I showed in the first GIF in the thread, how do I add it? Again, many thanks! @Chris
